# I am adding and deleting the row dynamically using jQuery, now i want the values entered into that to store into DB using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, database

Below is the code of jQuery which helps me to add and delete the row dynamically, but now i want to add the data entered into these dynamic rows into DB and specifically using ASP.NET.I am not getting any idea and very much new to ASP.NET. And there 2 fields which accepts the date. Help me out please!.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var lastChar = 1, newRow;
        get_lastID = function () {
            var id = $('#experience_table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("name");
            lastChar = parseInt(id.substr(id.length - 2), 10);
            lastChar = lastChar + 1;
            newRow = "<tr> \
        <td><input type='text'  name='company_name_0" + lastChar + "' maxlength='255' /></td> \
        <td><input type='text' class='datePicker' name='from_0" + lastChar + "'  /></td> \
        <td><input type='text'  class='datePicker' name='to_0" + lastChar + "'  /></td> \
        <td><input type='number' name='Total_exp_0" + lastChar + "' maxlength='11' /></td> \
                <td><input type='button' value='Delete' class = 'del_ExperienceRow' /></td> \
            </tr>"

        }
        $("#add_ExperienceRow").on("click", function () {

            if ($('#experience_table tr').size() <= 9) {
                get_lastID();
                $('#experience_table tbody').append(newRow);
            } else {
                alert("Reached Maximum Rows!");
            };
            $('.datePicker').datepicker();

        });
            $('.datePicker').datepicker();
        $(document).on('click', '.del_ExperienceRow', function () {

            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            lastChar = lastChar - 2;
        });


        });

    });
```

Comment: You can pickup the data using Request["key"] after POSTing. You should however increment the number on the <input>'s to tell them apart.

Comment: From my experiences with jQuery and asp.net, you will have to use asp controls inside the jQuery to be able to call it server side.

Comment: At the end of the day, it will all boil down to standard `HTTP POST` or `GET` (also PUT/DELETE). As the answers suggest - re: using jquery Ajax/Post/Get -> some target which could be a page, ashx, web service, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a save button that will store all your rows and the entered data in an array and send the data to the server like this:

```
function saveRows() {
    var data = []; // Creates an array

    // Create a foreach loop over all rows
    $("#experience_table tr").each(function() { 
        var row = $(this);

        // This adds an element to the array for the current row, containing an 
        // anonymous object with the data of the current row
        data.push({ someData: $(row).find("td.experience").val() }); 
    });

    $.ajax( { ... } ) // Create ajax call to your server (webservice)
}
```

Then you will need a webservice on the serverside. This is the ASP.NET part.
I would suggest you to setup a WCF service. Take a look at a tutorial here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627082/How-to-Consume-WCF-Service-using-JavaScript-Proxy

If you have further questions feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I send an email with ASP and jQuery. The principles are the same so You will be able to adapt it well.

**jQuery**

```
function sendEmail() {
   $("#email").dialog({
       modal: true,
       width: 550,
       buttons: {
            "Send": function () {
                var btn = document.getElementById("<%=lbSend.ClientID %>");
                if (btn) btn.click();
                $(this).dialog("close");
             },
             Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
             }
          }
        });
        jQuery("#email").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));//this is key as it makes sure it finds the textboxes within the dialog. Without this, you will insert blank values. 
        }
```

**ASP**

```
<div class="popUpStyle" title="Send Email" id="email" style="display: none">
     <asp:Label ID="lblTo" runat="server" Text="To: " Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSendTo" Text=""></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblFrom" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="From: "></asp:Label><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSendFrom" Text="Training.Registration@JeffWyler.com"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Subject: "></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="tbSubject" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
     <br />
      <asp:Label ID="lblBody" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Message:"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <asp:TextBox ID="tbMessage" runat="server" Width="515px" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="150px"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSend" runat="server" Text="" Width="50px" Font-Size="smaller" OnClick="lbSend_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
 </div>
```

**Code Behind C#**

```
protected void lbSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code to your database
}
```

So with yours, you will have to change it around a bit. You will have to create a function that calls a hidden "div." As you can tell, in the ASP markup, I am using asp controls, so I can call them from the behind code. I also use a link button with no text (if you set visible to false, you are unable to fire the button). In my jQuery, I created my own "Send" button and search for the link button within the div and once that "Send" button is clicked, the link button event is fired. Like I said before, this is sending an email so your button click event will be different. If you need help writing to the DB, let me know!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will not use postbacks for this, as this creates large loading times of the website, increases server load and lowers user experience. An AJAX call would be much better IMO

Comment: Agreed, but if you don't want to use a webservice, this is still a solution. I use the above code and the loading times are minimal. If you aren't inserting large amount of data, (which it looks like he's inserting 4 values) he shouldn't see long loading times.